# How much to charge for mobile apps? Why is $0.99 a bad idea?

Tags: e-commerce

I'm thinking about making some apps for phones. For the sake of this discussion say it's a generic *Yet Another Zombie Shooter* game, for Android, iPhone, Blackberry, or OVI Market. It is a kind of casual game that the customer would fire up while in boring class in school or waiting for a bus to come in. Let's also say that the game basically doesn't cost me anything to make, because I have a day job, and I make these apps in my free time.

The question is, **how much to charge for this kind of app**. I'd be perfectly happy with $0.99 price tag, but as I've read some articles about this on the 'net, they say that people see product's quality reflected in the price, so they'd consider $0.99 game inferior to $2.99 game. Something called a Perceived value pricing.

To summarize this, some profits would be nice, but I'm not aiming to rake what I can from the customers. But on the other side, I also don't want to release the software for free, a little extra money always come in handy.

P.S. I've read Joel's Camels and Rubber Duckies, but this is a different type of market.

Comment: Perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum.